# Change the FullSummaryGraphic size for deep neural networks

Tags: graphics, neural-networks

I am using the "FullSummaryGraphics" of a neural network:

```
NetInformation[model,"FullSummaryGraphic"]
```

After having the following result:
[image]
I would like to modify its size and the denotations. However, by dragging it, the image would rotate. This never happens for versions before 12.0.
Could anyone help?
Many thanks!